# Why is konsole reading /etc/passwd?

Tags: security, users, konsole

In relation to this question:

While  observing the behavior of fatrace, I notice something which concerns me.
Here are the first few lines of output of the command "fatrace|grep konsole"

```
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): CO /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): C /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): C /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): C /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): C /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): C /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): C /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): C /etc/passwd
konsole(4112): O /etc/passwd
...
```

The thing is that lsof|grep passwd shows that passwd is not open by any process.

So any idea what is going on?

Comment: Why would it be a security concern that Konsole reads from `/etc/passwd`? This file contains all the information about user accounts, including the home directory and shell.

Comment: @Gilles: You answered your own question. :)

Comment: Security concern: No.  Performance concern: somewhat.  There's a long reported (2013) and recently fixed (upstream, Aug 2016) KDE bug about this: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325442

Answer (score 9):

You can read the source code; speaking of... I did it for you; it looks like it's from the `ProcessInfo.cpp` file. It's getting the usernames. Not only that `/etc/passwd` isn't a concern for you, anyone can read it. You might be worried though if it was trying to read `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: I think the bigger questions are: Why isn't lsof registering it? Why doesn't konsole just read /etc/paswd once? Also why does konsole need a list of usernames?

Answer (score 8):

Using `strace` you can see what `konsole` is up to.

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o konsole.log
...
...
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2655, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f316d8fc000
read(3, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\nbin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin\ndaemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin\nadm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin\nlp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin\nsync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sy
nc\nshutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown\nhalt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt\nmail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin\noperator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin\ngames:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin\nf
tp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin\nnobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin\ndbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin\nsystemd-journal-gateway:x:191:191:Journal Gateway:/var/log/journal:/usr/sbin/nologin\npolkitd:
x:999:999:User for polkitd:/:/sbin/nologin\nusbmuxd:x:113:113:usbmuxd user:/:/sbin/nologin\ncolord:x:998:997:User for colord:/var/lib/colord:/sbin/nologin\nrpc:x:32:32:Rpcbind Daemon:/var/lib/rpcbind:/sbin/nologin\nqemu:x:107:
107:qemu user:/:/sbin/nologin\nrtkit:x:172:172:RealtimeKit:/proc:/sbin/nologin\ntss:x:59:59:Account used by the trousers package to sandbox the tcsd daemon:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin\nradvd:x:75:75:radvd user:/:/sbin/nologin\nabr
t:x:173:173::/etc/abrt:/sbin/nologin\nopenvpn:x:997:996:OpenVPN:/etc/openvpn:/sbin/nologin\nunbound:x:996:995:Unbound DNS resolver:/etc/unbound:/sbin/nologin\nsaslauth:x:995:76:\"Saslauthd user\":/run/saslauthd:/sbin/nologin\n
avahi:x:70:70:Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/sbin/nologin\navahi-autoipd:x:170:170:Avahi IPv4LL Stack:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/sbin/nologin\nrpcuser:x:29:29:RPC Service User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin\nnfsnobody
:x:65534:65534:Anonymous NFS User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin\nnm-openconnect:x:994:994:NetworkManager user for OpenConnect:/:/sbin/nologin\nmailnull:x:47:47::/var/spool/mqueue:/sbin/nologin\nsmmsp:x:51:51::/var/spool/mqueue:/s
bin/nologin\nsshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin\ntcpdump:x:72:72::/:/sbin/nologin\npulse:x:993:993:PulseAudio System Daemon:/var/run/pulse:/sbin/nologin\ngdm:x:42:42::/var/lib/gdm:/sbin/nologin\
ngnome-initial-"..., 4096) = 2655
close(3)                                = 0
...
```

Konsole is reading the contents of `/etc/passwd` in fairly quickly and you're just not seeing it with `lsof`. This is a typical issue when a file is opened, read quickly, and then closed.

#### Should I be concerned?

This, by the way, is of no concern. My `gnome-terminal` does the same thing. The flow of things can be a bit confusing but Konsole is querying the system for a piece of information. In this case something like the user's home directory.

So the system makes a call to NSS (Name Service Switch configuration file):

```
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

There's a line in this file, specifically this line:

```
passwd:     files
```

This line tells NSS where the "database" 'passwd' can be found. This line is telling NSS that the resource is located in files. So the system then opens up the `/etc/passwd` file to look for the user's home directory.

**NOTE:** Digging further this behavior seems to be caused by Bash. Doing an `strace` of just Bash shows the same thing.

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o bash.log bash
```

#### Further readings

If you're genuinely interested in how NSS works then consult the man pages `nsswitch.conf` and `nss`. NSS is modular and can use different backend technologies for its "databases".

For example:

```
       /etc/nsswitch.conf       NSS configuration file.
       /lib/libnss_compat.so.X  implements "compat" source.
       /lib/libnss_db.so.X      implements "db" source.
       /lib/libnss_dns.so.X     implements "dns" source.
       /lib/libnss_files.so.X   implements "files" source.
       /lib/libnss_hesiod.so.X  implements "hesiod" source.
       /lib/libnss_nis.so.X     implements "nis" source.
       /lib/libnss_nisplus.so.X implements "nisplus" source.
```

Comment: It isn't `/etc/nsswitch.conf` that triggers the loading of `/etc/passwd`, rather the opposite. Konsole wants to obtain some information about user accounts, so it opens `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, which tells it (inside libc code, not inside code from the Konsole source) that the user accounts are in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @Gilles - OK, I'll reword that part, thanks.

Comment: @Gilles - updated.

Answer (score 8):

For the same reason `ls -l` reads /etc/passwd, it is the data that associates UIDs with names. When `ls` calls `stat(2)` on a file it gets a numeric UID for the owner of the file. In order to display that as a human readable name, it needs to look it up in the only place that has those associations, `/etc/passwd`. For example a typical first line in `/etc/passwd` is

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

When `ls -l /etc/hosts` needs to produce the output

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 222 Jan 14  2013 /etc/hosts
```

it needs to translate the UID 0 into "root" for so it calls a library routine like [getpwuid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) which reads `/etc/passwd` to provide the translation. That's a large part of the reason `/etc/passwd` exists: to provide such translations for completely mundane purposes.

Looking up user names presents no more of a security issue than calling [localtime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) so that `ls` can tell you "Jan 14 2013" for the modification time of the file. As [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125506/1294) noted, there's no reason to keep the file open, so it is closed as soon as its contents are read.

The file `/etc/passwd` did originally contain hashed passwords in simpler times. The password hashes were moved to `/etc/shadow` which normal users cannot read because it was a security hole. The name `/etc/passwd` stayed the same but now contains `x` in the former password hash field which is not a valid hash for any password.